# Trying to write a recursion function in racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a regular recursion function and a tail-recursion function which takes four arguments and evaluates the sum of `ax^2 + b` for `x` from `q` to `r`.

This is what I have so far and it is not working, can I get some information on what is wrong with my code?

```
(define (sumof a b q r)

  (define (sum) 
    (+ (* (expt q 2) a) b))

  (if ( = q r)
      0
      (+ (+ q 1) (sum))))
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that is not looping, at some point you need to go to the next value of  `q` and that's simply not happening. Use recursion for implementing iteration, and if possible use tail recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct way to call the recursion:

```
(define (sumof a b q r)
  (define (sum q) (+ (* (expt q 2) a) b))
  (if (= q r)
      0
      (+ (sum q)
         (sumof a b (+ q 1) r))))
```

You should pass along the parameter that changes at each iteration, that's cleaner than capturing it from the defining environment. And notice how the `sumof` function must call itself for iterating. As a side note, your function is *not* tail-recursive. A proper tail recursion would look like this:

```
(define (sumof a b q r)
  (define (sum x) (+ (* a x x) b))
  (let loop ((q q) (acc 0))
    (if (= q r)
        acc
        (loop (+ q 1) (+ (sum q) acc)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not surprising that it is difficult to write code. Though recursion is useful, this is about the worst way to introduce it because using recursion for this problem goes against any inclination toward sound software engineering practice.

### Mathematic Specification

Looking at the basic equation:

[image: sigma for x from q to r in a x squared plus b]

It's clear that the problem isn't fully specified. Is it `x < r` or `x <= r`? At least writing a specification made the assumption that might lead to an [off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error explicit.

### Implementation

I meant what I said about this problem being detrimental to sound software engineering. There are places for recursion. Those places are exactly where recursion makes the code clearer and easier to understand. This is **not** one of those cases. This is a case where the specification is iterative and writing the implementation recursively adds complexity and opacity.

If we stay close to the specification:

```
#lang racket

(provide sumof)

(define/contract (sumof a b q r)
  (number? number? number? number? . -> . number?)
  
  (define/contract (sigma list-of-numbers f)
    ((listof number?) (number? . -> . number?) . -> . number?)
    (foldl + 0 (map f list-of-numbers)))

  ;; range will return '() if r + 1 >= q
  (define q<=x<=r (range q (add1 r)))
  
  ;; a and b are already in lexical scope
  (define (ax^2+b x)
    (+ (* a x x) b))
  
  ;; if the range is empty return zero
  ;; becuase zero is the identity of addition
  (if (pair? q<=x<=r)
   (sigma  q<=x<=r ax^2+b)
   0))
```

This uses the high level operators `map` and `foldl` that all today's cool languages think are the cat's meow. Perhaps because it lets us write things like `(sigma  q<=x<=r ax^2+b)`.

### But it's HomeWork

What makes this so bad is the Computer Science of tail-recursion is founded on the isomorphism between a particular class of recursive descriptions of  algorithms and iterative descriptions. The idea of a programming language is to make reading and writing our programs easier.

Though one would never guess it based on the assignment `#lang racket` includes a construct exactly for the purpose of explicitly expressing the isomorphism of tail-recursion and writing tail-recursive algorithms more clearly.

```
#lang racket

(provide sumof)

(define/contract (sumof a b q r)
  (number? number? number? number? . -> . number?)
  
  ;; a and b are already in lexical scope
  (define (ax^2+b x)
    (+ (* a x x) b))
  
  (if (< q r)
      (let loop ([x-range (range q (add1 r))]
                 [sigma 0])
        (cond 
          [(null? x-range) sigma]
          [else (loop (rest x-range)
                      (+ (ax^2+b (first x-range))
                         sigma))]))
      0))
```

The `(let loop...` syntax makes it clear that the tail-recursive call is really a loop.